# socket io not giving the desired output

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I have created a index.js which loads index.html using sockets.
the server is running successfully and also the index.html page loads. but cant append the written text in the div.

**index.js**

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("SERVER CREATED WITH PORT 3000");
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('send', function(data) {
        io.sockets.emit('new', data);
    });
});
```

**index.html**

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>chat</title>
    <style>
        #chat {
            height: 500px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="chat"></div>
    <form id="send-message">
        <input id="message" />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
    <h1>Working</h1>
    <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(function($) {
            var socket = io.connect();
            var $messageform = $('#send-message');
            var $messagebox = $('#message');
            var $chat = $('#chat');

            $messageform.submit(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                socket.emit('send', $messagebox.val());
                $messagebox.val('');
            });
            socket.on('new', function(data) {
                $chat.append(data + "<br />");
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

These are the files which I have created and want to send the text to all tabs.
The browser just gets refreshed without loading the text when submit is hit.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What have you tried for debugging this? Have you added console.log to see what's running and what's not?

Comment: Nope. I am new to sockets .

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your even listener hence the "refresh" taking place and `.preventDefault();` not being run. Have you tried to change your event listener? maybe to `.on('submit',function(e){});` or maybe place a `console.log("Form submit called");` into the event function to see if it ever runs?